# httprequest getting back PHP functions and variables

Tags: php, http

How does one access and receive back a variable from a PHP file with a HTTP Request?

I have gotten a HTTP Request to connect to my .PHP file. What I wanted to do next is for example reference that I want to receive `$testvariable = 1;` back but I have no idea where to begin. The HTTP parameters don't really let me reference this $testvariable directly.

What if the PHP file has simply one function and at the end of it it does a `return $testvariable;`? Would HTTP receive back this one variable? What if I need more than one. Maybe try and get the PHP to place parameters in the URL and the HTTP reads those parameters in the url? Maybe these "headers" are key to this...

Comment: A HTTP response is just what the URL you're calling outputs. If you make a HTTP request to a PHP page that just contains: `<?php echo 1;`, then the response of that request would be `1`. Normally, you want to be able to return multiple values in some common format you can parse, which is why it's very common to return the data as JSON. You need to do some more research and testing to learn the basics.

Comment: How would I know if HTTP got back this ```1``` that was echoed? HTTP just find whatever is in the body tags and takes it? Would I have to use something like GET or POST if I wanted HTTP request to pass in a variable first and they get back something? If so, where would I be able to read about all this in a beginner sort of terminology...

Comment: I'm seeing a ```HttpRequest.ResponseContent``` and I think this is what HTTP gets back whatever I need but how do I get my number in this response. Yes. I need the PHP variable back in that response.

Comment: A client (like the browser) makes a request to a specific URL on a server. The server then executes your code (like your PHP code). _Anything_ that script outputs will be part of the response to the client. The body tag is only relevant if you return a HTML page. If you just want to return a value, just output that value. If you want to return multiple values, then return the values formatted in some way you can read on the client (like JSON, XML or something like that).

Comment: I see, makes sense now. The HTTP Request receives back the entire page and I assume this ```.ResponseContent``` contains everything from ```<html>...``` everything in the middle to ```</html>```. Since I'm just looking if the response is EQUAL to ```1``` it has all the other rubbish inbetween it. 

Is there a way to sanitise that? Clean it up? Remove the tags that I don't need. Is this what JSON does and if so, how does it do it. Where should I look.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it out. HTTP Request gets back ALL that is on your HTML page. It seems like it ignores `<html><body>` tags but everything else in the body gets taken back at your response. Even if your answer is `" 1 "` but you have a single space around it your response is 1 including blank spaces. You need a clean `"1"`.

Passing variables works by using the contents field. You place your values and assign them to a string like `number=` that then gets posted on the page. When a page is loaded, it can look for a variable under the same name like `$test = $_POST['number'];` and take the value within that variable and use it further where it needs to on your page.